# Tensorflow SSD object detection classes selection

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, object-detection

I am working on the basic tensorflow object detection example [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection)
it is detecting all 90 classes from coco dataset. But I want to detect only two classes from it. how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you want to detect a **motorcycle** and a **person** only. 
inside the file, visualization_util.py , go to the def draw_bounding_box_on_image_array 
, there is a function :

```
  draw_bounding_box_on_image(image_pil, ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax, color,
                         thickness, display_str_list,
                         use_normalized_coordinates)
```

put this function call inside a condition like this

```
if (display_str_list[0][0:3]=="per" or display_str_list[0][0:3]=="mot"):

  draw_bounding_box_on_image(image_pil, ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax, color,
                         thickness, display_str_list,
                         use_normalized_coordinates)
```

here "per" is the first three letters of "person" and "mot" is first three letter of motorcycle. In this way, you can detect your desired object out of all others